# Mediasoup installation failed on windows

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, npm, webrtc, mediasoup

I am trying to install mediasoup version 3, and here is the error that occurs during the installation:

```
$ npm i mediasoup --save
some dependencies like ninja and meson are installed successful.
/f/allMy/Projects/Practice/WebRTC/Mediasoup/node_modules/mediasoup/worker/out/pip/bin/meson setup \    
npm ERR!                --prefix /f/allMy/Projects/Practice/WebRTC/Mediasoup/node_modules/mediasoup/worker/out/Release \
npm ERR!                --bindir '' \
npm ERR!                --libdir '' \
npm ERR!                --buildtype release \
npm ERR!                -Db_ndebug=true \
npm ERR!                -Db_pie=true \
npm ERR!                -Db_staticpic=true \
npm ERR!                --reconfigure \
npm ERR!                --vsenv \
npm ERR!                /f/allMy/Projects/Practice/WebRTC/Mediasoup/node_modules/mediasoup/worker/out/Release/build || \
npm ERR!                /f/allMy/Projects/Practice/WebRTC/Mediasoup/node_modules/mediasoup/worker/out/pip/bin/meson setup \
npm ERR!                        --prefix /f/allMy/Projects/Practice/WebRTC/Mediasoup/node_modules/mediasoup/worker/out/Release \
npm ERR!                        --bindir '' \
npm ERR!                        --libdir '' \
npm ERR!                        --buildtype release \
npm ERR!                        -Db_ndebug=true \
npm ERR!                        -Db_pie=true \
npm ERR!                        -Db_staticpic=true \
npm ERR!                        --vsenv \
npm ERR!                        /f/allMy/Projects/Practice/WebRTC/Mediasoup/node_modules/mediasoup/worker/out/Release/build
npm ERR! The Meson build system
npm ERR! Version: 0.61.5
npm ERR! Source dir: F:\allMy\Projects\Practice\WebRTC\Mediasoup\node_modules\mediasoup\worker
npm ERR! Build dir: F:\allMy\Projects\Practice\WebRTC\Mediasoup\node_modules\mediasoup\worker\out\Release\build
npm ERR! Build type: native build
npm ERR! Project name: mediasoup-worker
npm ERR! Project version: undefined
npm ERR!
npm ERR! meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Could not find C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe
npm ERR!
npm ERR! A full log can be found at F:\allMy\Projects\Practice\WebRTC\Mediasoup\node_modules\mediasoup\worker\out\Release\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
npm ERR! make: Leaving directory `/f/allMy/Projects/Practice/WebRTC/Mediasoup/node_modules/mediasoup/worker'    
npm ERR! Usage:   
npm ERR!   c:\Users\tonys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python3.exe -m pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
npm ERR!   c:\Users\tonys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python3.exe -m pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
npm ERR!   c:\Users\tonys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python3.exe -m pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
npm ERR!   c:\Users\tonys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python3.exe -m pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
npm ERR!   c:\Users\tonys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python3.exe -m pip install [options] <archive 
url/path> ...
npm ERR!
npm ERR! no such option: --system
npm ERR! Directory does not contain a valid build tree:
npm ERR! F:\allMy\Projects\Practice\WebRTC\Mediasoup\node_modules\mediasoup\worker\out\Release\build
npm ERR! make: *** [setup] Error 1
npm ERR! npm-scripts.js [ERROR] executeCmd() failed, exiting: Error: Command failed: make -C worker
```

My versions:

**Python**:**3.11**

**VSCode**:**1.77.3**

**Node Js**:**16.13.1**

I have already tried installing via Yarn, but that did not solve it.

Comment: I am having the same thing but with node 18 and python 3.9

Comment: @Stranger, it works for me inside a docker container but does not work on the window.  so change environment from window to Linux.

Comment: It worked for me in linux too, I figured out what the issue was. In my windows machine I didn't have visual studio C++ (Any version after 2011) with MsBuild (Yes, this specific type of build component), that is required to run this. I reinstalled visual studio's c++ environment, and then reinstalled mediasoup and it worked.

Comment: oh and btw, just mentioning, the command you are using in your question is wrong afaik, the authentic version includes the version number like so: `npm install mediasoup@3`

Comment: Can you tell me? it needs to integrate Visual Studio C++ into Visual Studio Code for installing Mediasoup. actually I am work on visual studio code as IDE. or just installing the Visual Studio C++.

Comment: nono, the visual studio code editor has nothing to do with Microsoft visual studio C++. What I am talking about is not VSCode, I am simply talking about VS, which are both different products by Microsoft. This is the one I am talking about https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ (NOT https://code.visualstudio.com/) 

So when you install visual studio, select the C++ dependencies, and make sure to select msbuild (or something of a similar name) and then start install. Once that is done, restart your computer and then retry the `npm install mediasoup@3` command.

Comment: Glad to hear, I'll post this as an answer, please accept it so that it helps others with the same problem as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we (I and the OP) discussed in the comments, this is the answer according to what worked for both of us on Windows. The problem was that Microsoft Visual Studio C++ wasn't installed, or not installed correctly. A required feature of mediasoup is msbuild, and maybe some other unidentified ones that are included in Microsoft Visual Studio C++.

**Steps to fix this issue:**

1. Download Visual Studio from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
2. Install, and make sure you have the C++ development options checked, if you further look into what it installs, you can see msbuild, and proceed with the installation including it, and the other essential tools it has checked by default for you.
3. After that, restart your computer.
4. Then go to your project folder again and retry the `npm install mediasoup@3` command, it should work now.

**Note:** This answer is for Windows only, I tried the `npm install mediasoup@3` command on my Debian machine that has make installed and it worked without requiring me to do any of the aforementioned steps. The same thing was noticed by the OP, that they tried this on Linux and it simply worked without any of this jargon.